# PowerShell/Windows Forms - How to add ScrollAble control to a tab?

Tags: powershell, winforms

I'm creating a form with WinForms and I want to add a scrollable area with multiple Labels and TextBoxes.

Here's my code for the form (there's more to it that's specific to my project, but this should be the gist of it):

```
$form                              = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.ClientSize                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(350,380)

$tabcontrol                        = New-object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl 
$tabcontrol.Size                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(330,330)
$tabcontrol.Location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$form.Controls.Add($tabcontrol)

$tab                               = New-object System.Windows.Forms.Tabpage
$tab.Text                          = "Tab1"
$tabcontrol.Controls.Add($tab)
```

I've tried adding a ScrollableControl to `$tab`:

```
$scroll                            = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl
$scroll.AutoScroll                 = $true
$scroll.AutoScrollMinSize          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (0, 200)
$scroll.VerticalScroll.LargeChange = 20
$scroll.VerticalScroll.SmallChange = 7
$tab.Controls.Add($scroll)
```

When I launch the form, there's no scroll bar or anything on Tab1 (`$tab`). I've tried adding controls to `$scroll`, like a System.Windows.Forms.Label or System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, but still nothing.

So what am I doing wrong? How would I add a scrollable control to `$tab`?

Comment: IIIRC, a tab page automatically gets a scrollbar when the content exceeds the size. So just insert controls into the tab page (outside the viewable area)

Comment: @PMF Interesting. I tried adding 20+ controls and after like 6 or so, it just gets cut off. No scroll bar, or any way to access the rest of the objects.

Comment: Works for me. Try setting `$tab.AutoScroll = true` and `$tab.Size = new Size(something very large)`

Comment: @PMF oh I see what I'm doing wrong. I'm setting the `AutoScroll = $true` on the ScrollableControl object (`$scroll.AutoScroll = $true`), not the Tabpage object (`$tab.AutoScroll = $true`). When I set `$tab.AutoScroll = $true`, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a ScrollableControl, you need to make sure the tab page is scrollable. Add this (with `$tab` being the Tab page):

```
$tab.AutoScroll = true
$tab.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (1000, 1000)
```

This will automatically provide a scrollbar when the Window is smaller than the content of the page.